# In Season 3 of Star Trek: Picard, is this race considered good or bad now?

Tags: star-trek, borg, star-trek-picard

In the **S3:E9 - "Vox"** of *Star Trek: Picard*, it is revealed that the Borg are the bad guys... but in season two the Borg had a change of heart and (under the leadership of Doctor Jurati as the new Borg queen) were no longer assimilating societies by force.

When did the Borg go back to being O.G. Borg?  What'd I miss?

Comment: If you are trying to classify every race into one of either "Good" or "Bad" then you have entirely missed the point of Star Trek Picard, and probably every Star Trek show.

Comment: This issue bugged our family as well. I tend to find alternative timelines and time travel irritating for the most part. Too easy for writers to ignore continuity and their own canons and escape the holes they dug themselves into regarding plot and character development. Sort of like the "Then they all woke up and it was a dream." 

Okay, it's science fiction and fantasy, and anything goes. My personal experience is that I like the challenge of making things make sense in a story and not relying on deus ex machina to bail me out.

Comment: @PatWagnerDenver There was also the revelation at the very end of Season 2, in the 21st century, that Wesley can now travel anywhere in space or time, so that undermines the sense of his mother being in any real peril from the Borg.

Comment: @DJClayworth I was trying to present a simplified description of what I was seeing in the show in a clear, concise manner.  To infer that I am trying to "classify every race" is preposterous. I would, however, like to thank you for being That Guy™; I can't imagine what life would be like without That Guy™, and persons like yourself continue to do everything they can to prevent that highly unlikely future.

Comment: @DJClayworth also, if you're referring to the title of the post, *someone else edited my original title.*

Comment: @jeffronicus Thanks for the reminder. I acknowledge it is difficult to maintain consistency while juggling plot lines and events going back decades. Nonetheless, I sometimes think the fans know the canon better than the show runners and writers. But that is why the gods created fan fiction, right? (grin) And this is all for fun. I am grateful that I live a life with the time and resources to indulge myself worrying about mythical characters and their actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jurati replaced the Borg Queen who was taken from an alternate timeline and, after traveling to the past of an unforked timeline, formed her own collective, then emerged into the "present" of *Picard*. The existing Borg Collective was apparently unaffected.

Based on a passing comment from Captain Shaw in Picard Season 3, Episode 4 "the real Borg are still out there."

This does not resolve all the questions one might have about the status of the Borg in Picard's current time, but this series rarely answers those.

Comment: this bring up the quesiton of whether Borq Queen Jurati can reverse/undo what was done to all the young Starfleet officers.

Comment: Jurati's borg teamed up with the federation and it was implied they were going to join the federation. At the very least they were going to be allies. Jurati's borg should also be several hundred years ahead of the current Borg in technology. And she should have warned Picard since she inherited the queens memories and known about the genetic alterations.

Comment: Additionally if the normal Borg can introduce these DNA changes from a transporter. They could also do it in person. Which means they could also replicate Jack's changes (which are 20-30 years old genetic changes implemented with Picard's assimilation, not new technology). Thus there's no reason to seek him.